# Is there a risk adding new (unused) jars to running tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, dynamic-class-loaders, tomcat8.5

I'm using Tomcat8.5 in production and I have several applications in webapps

Is there a risk **before** loading (and restarting) new application version, just adding new (which will currently be unused) dependency jars (as commons) to WEB-INF\lib folder

and after a while uploading (code that will use the new jars) and restarting the server?

Can there be any exceptions or errors?

Notice I'm not upgrading or deleting jars, only adding jars that didn't exists before.

When updating existing jars you may get exception as

```
 java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file. (Params: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourcesInternal(StandardRoot.java:327)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResources(CachedResource.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResources(Cache.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResources(StandardRoot.java:315)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResources(StandardRoot.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:939)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1142)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the newly added dependencies are not used as a dependency on any of the existing jars you're using?

Comment: @Aris How can it be used if it isn't exists ?(should be used in new version about to upload)